# Nodejs: Convenience logger depending on environment

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am attempting to create a convenience function to log messages to console depending on environment. The intend is to log to console only in the `dev` environment.

My implementation works for messages string, but unable to catch error traces. Code so far:

```
//Convenience function
function log() {
    let message = ""

    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        message += arguments[i] + " "
    }

    if (env == "dev") {
        console.log(message.trim())
    }
}

//Usage
let number = 1
logger.log("Some messages", number) //prints "Some messages 1", works ok.
```

However, if it's an error trace like so, it would only log the string messages, not the whole json-ish trace.

```
{ Error
   at BaseExceptionClosure (/Users/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:666:29)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:669:2)
   at __w_pdfjs_require__ (/Users/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:52:30)
   at Object.defineProperty.value (/Users/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:129:23)
   at __w_pdfjs_require__ (/Users/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:52:30)
   at pdfjsVersion (/Users/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:116:18)
   at /node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:119:10
   at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (/Users/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:25:20)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:32:3)
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
 message: 'Invalid PDF structure',
 name: 'InvalidPDFException' } }

logger.log("Err from api", err) //Unable to log err traces like above
```

How can I pass the whole argument from the `log` into the `console.log` so that the logging behaves as a normal `console.log`.

Comment: use env === "dev" instead of env == "dev"

Comment: Which logging library are you using?

Comment: I’m not using any logging library @Dez

Answer (score 0):

You can stringify your error object then log that to your console.

```js
const stringifiedError = JSON.stringify(err);

logger.log("Err from api", stringifiedError)
```